# GNOME Panel seen in Unity 2D?

Tags: gnome-panel, unity-2d

Why does GNOME panel open up when I launch UNITY 2D instead of Unity panel?
This I am starting to see from last 2 days, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I only see it when I run the command `gnome-panel` at the command prompt. So I think you need to make sure that `gnome-panel` isn't running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well finally solved, I needed to do the following

1. `gnome-panel --replace`
2. `unity-2d-launcher &`
3. Save the session and logout

Answer (score 1):

What's *likely* happening is that `gnome-panel` is set to run *on login*, and as such it'll automatically start *every* time you log into GNOME. So, what you can do is to open up Startup Application Preferences (AKA `gnome-session-properties`), and check for something that has a you don't know what it is, then you want "Edit" that item, and see what comes up.

[image: Example.]

Keep going through the list until you find the `gnome-panel` command tucked away somewhere.

Comment: I don't have gnome-panel set to run at startup, this is the first thing I verified. Not sure why this issue is coming. 
Is there a way to kill gnome-panel I tried kill but it kept restarting.

Comment: Hmm. I'd run `killall gnome-panel` - that worked for me once I started it.

Comment: No matter how many times I execute killall gnome-panel even with sudo as well it still keeps coming again and again :(